# Windows caches 403 machine-wide?

Tags: windows, cache

In all honesty, I have no idea how to formulate this question, it's the weirdest thing I've ever encountered.

When developing a website on an external VPS and I encounter on my desktop a 403 or 404 message, it for some reason doesn't actually communicate with the server anymore (I can tell from the apache log files) and it will keep showing 403 for the `/` (root, ie: `http://www.domain.com/`) and a 404 for any non-root (ie: `http://www.domain.com/*`).

This happens not only in the browser I worked in, but also in firefox, IE, edge, etc and will keep happening until I restart my desktop after which it will function normal until I encounter a 403 or 404 again after which the problem happens again.

Using another laptop and my mobile phone (as well as the apache server logs) I can confirm it's not the server actually returning a 403 or 404, but just my windows machine returning the result.

In my network there is no caching server or anything, just a regular home network with a couple switches and a simple router/modem straight to the ISP.

Running windows 10 Enterprise edition (x64), updated all browsers to their latest versions as well as installed all updates to the OS.

**EDIT:** Using Wireshark on my desktop it does actually send a package out to the server and receives an 403/404 header in return, so the issue does seem to be server-side.
Although I'd have no idea how a restart would make a difference since different browsers don't share cookies..

**EDIT2:** The server shows no packages beeing received nor sent, when reaching via browser directly on it's IP it does show packages beeing sent/received

Comment: By definition, the 403 error you're receiving *must* be sent by a webserver. It's not an error your browser can just gin up on its own.

Comment: And yet it happens, I know it sounds unbelievable, but I'm 100% serious here

Comment: Perform a packet capture at the client and at the server (and possible along the network path somewhere as well) to see where it's coming from.

Comment: used wireshark on my desktop, for now I have no way to get a packet capture to run on my VPS (I only have SSH access)

Comment: `tcpdump` runs just fine via ssh.

Comment: ah, yes that works, unfortunatly it seems no traffic is passing when this problem is happening

Comment: If tcpdump on the server doesn't show anything, then something in between is modifying your traffic.

Comment: but how is that possible when a restart fixes the issue? there's no header information that really changes when you restart a computer

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem for you to track down. :)

Comment: hah.. yeah.. currently mildly frustrating as I'm just trying to develop a website, which doesn't go smoothly when you have to restart your PC every now and then.. Just going to hope someone comes up with a brilliant idea to try

Comment: Hint: look into your antivirus/antimalware software (if you have some running). I've seen those throw HTTP errors if their web filtering component goes awry (which would also be solved via a reboot).

Comment: If it works via IP address, then DNS may be the issue.  What is doing name resolution?

Comment: Tried disabling it, no change. Now restarting doesn't help anymore either, I'm at a loss

Comment: stupid question, but you have completely cleared your browser cache, right?

Comment: Yeah I did, no special things going on in DNS either, using the google DNS servers; website uses cloudflare (currently in developer mode, all caching disabled/purged). Never had this issue before either (ran plenty of websites with cloudflare)

Comment: my laptop now has the same issue too, I'll contact my ISP tomorrow, maybe they know something of what's going on.